# Lower bound for degree of polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial such that
$$|f(x)|<\epsilon\quad\text{for all $x$ with }|x|<1.$$
Can we find an explicit lower bound for the degree of $f$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Comment: Any polynomial can be scaled to have this property.  If you want information about the degree, you have to add a limitation to compensate—for example, we could ask that $f$ be monic, or that $f(2)=1$, or something like this.

Answer (score 5):

There is no upper bound, $f(x) = \epsilon x^n$ works for every $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The lower bound is the degree of the zero polynomial.

Comment: +$1$ for answering the question of whether or not there is a *lower* bound.

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is just to make $$ f(x) = \epsilon - c$$  $\forall \; 0<c\leq\epsilon \;$ this shows why the lower bound is degree zero.